# How to extend ggplot2 boxplot with ggproto?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, boxplot, ggproto

I'm often using boxplots in my work and like `ggplot2` aesthetics. But standard `geom_boxplot` lacks two things important for me: ends of whiskers and median labels. Thanks to information from here I've written a function:

```
gBoxplot <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL, font = "CMU Serif", fsize = 18){
  require(ggplot2)
  vars <- all.vars(formula)
  response <- vars[1]
  factor <- vars[2]
  # A function for medians labelling
  fun_med <- function(x){
    return(data.frame(y = median(x), label = round(median(x), 3)))
  }
  p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = factor, y = response)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.6) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = fun_med, geom = "label", family = font, size = fsize/3, 
                                                                         vjust = -0.1) +
  theme_grey(base_size = fsize, base_family = font)
  return(p)
}
```

There are also font settings, but this is just because I'm too lazy to make a theme. Here is an example:

```
gBoxplot(hwy ~ class, mpg)
```

[image: plot1]

Good enough for me, but there are some restrictictions (cannot use auto-dodging, etc.), and it will be better to make a new geom based on `geom_boxplot`. I've read the vignette [Extending ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html), but cannot understand how to implement it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So what do you think?

Comment: Great thanks, @MikeWise! See comment for your answer.

Comment: Err, which comment? And if you like it, could you accept the answer? To do that, click on the grey check-mark under then vote-number near the top-left of my answer.

Comment: OK, I've accepted!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So been thinking about this one for a while. Basically when you create a new primitive, you normally write a combination of:

1. A  **layer-function**
2. A **stat-ggproto**,
3. A **geom-ggproto**

Only the **layer-function** need be visible to the user. You only need to write a **stat-ggproto** if you need some new way of transforming your data to make your primitive. And you only need write a **geom-ggproto** if you have some new grid-based graphics to create.

In this case, where we are basically composting **layer-function** that already exist, we don’t really need to write new ggprotos. It is enough to write a new **layer-function**. This **layer-function** will create the three layers that you already are using and map the parameters the way you intend. In this case:

- Layer1 – uses `geom_errorbar` and `stat_boxplot` – to get our errorbars
- Layer2 – uses `geom_boxplot` and `stat_boxplot` - to create the boxplots
- Layer3 – users `geom_label` and `stat_summary`  - to create the text labels  with the mean value in the center of the boxes.

Of course you could write a new **stat-ggproto** and a new **geom-ggproto** that do all of these things at once. Or maybe you compost `stat_summary` and `stat_boxplot` into one, and the three **geom-protos** as well, and this do this with one layer. But there is little point unless we have efficiency problems.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
geom_myboxplot <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL,
                           stat = "boxplot", position = "dodge",coef=1.5,
                           font = "sans", fsize = 18, width=0.6,
                           fun.data = NULL, fun.y = NULL, fun.ymax = NULL,
                           fun.ymin = NULL, fun.args = list(),
                           outlier.colour = NULL, outlier.color = NULL,
                           outlier.shape = 19, outlier.size = 1.5,outlier.stroke = 0.5,
                           notch = FALSE,  notchwidth = 0.5,varwidth = FALSE,
                           na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE,...) {
    vars <- all.vars(formula)
    response <- vars[1]
    factor <- vars[2]
    mymap <- aes_string(x=factor,y=response)
    fun_med <- function(x) {
        return(data.frame(y = median(x), label = round(median(x), 3)))
    }
    position <- position_dodge(width)
    l1 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mymap, stat = StatBoxplot,
            geom = "errorbar", position = position, show.legend = show.legend,
            inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(na.rm = na.rm,
                coef = coef, width = width, ...))
    l2 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mymap, stat = stat, geom = GeomBoxplot,
            position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
            params = list(outlier.colour = outlier.colour, outlier.shape = outlier.shape,
                outlier.size = outlier.size, outlier.stroke = outlier.stroke,
                notch = notch, notchwidth = notchwidth, varwidth = varwidth,
                na.rm = na.rm, ...))
    l3 <- layer(data = data, mapping = mymap, stat = StatSummary,
            geom = "label", position = position, show.legend = show.legend,
            inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(fun.data = fun_med,
                fun.y = fun.y, fun.ymax = fun.ymax, fun.ymin = fun.ymin,
                fun.args = fun.args, na.rm=na.rm,family=font,size=fsize/3,vjust=-0.1,...))
    return(list(l1,l2,l3))
}
```

which allows you to create your customized boxplots it now like this:

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_myboxplot( hwy ~ class, font = "sans",fsize = 18)+
  theme_grey(base_family = "sans",base_size = 18 )
```

And they look like this:

[image]

**Note**: we did not actually have to use the `layer` function, we could have used the orginal `stat_boxplot`, `geom_boxplot`, and `stat_summary` calls in their place. But we still would have had to fill in all the parameters if we wanted to be able to control them from our custom boxplot, so I think it was clearer this way - at least from the point-of-view of structure as opposed to functionality.  Maybe it isn't though, it is a matter of taste...

Also I don't have that font which does look a lot nicer. But I did not feel like tracking it down and installing it.

Comment: I've lost hope for any answer, so view yours just now. Really it's the very thing: working example and some theory to think about. Need some time to load the idea in mind (English is not my motherlang).  The font I use is [Computer Modern Unicode](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/), a unicode version of D. Knuth's classic.

Comment: Great. Glad you like it. Please accept the answer though.

Comment: Thanks. If you had two more points you could upvote it too. Maybe next time :)

Comment: @MikeWise Do you know how I could adapt this approach to adjust positions for e.g. points or polygons?  I'm looking to develop a function where overlapping geometric objects are shifted so they don't overlap, probably using a force-direction approach. Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: The example above shifts the points to avoid collisions. Are you talking about new gemos that you define, or are you looking to layer other already existing geoms.