# Extending ggplot functionality with ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485110/1156245) addresses how to extend ggplot functionality using ggproto, specifically on a boxplot example. I wonder how this approach might be generalised.

For instance let's say I want to implement an algorithm to adjust the position of geom_point elements to reduce point overlapping (such as `ggrepel` does for labels).  Grateful for a steer on how to approach this problem - i.e. how to access and edit the x/y values and point size parameters (for overlap identification).  I'm assuming the solution is linked to ggproto, but if that's wrong I'd welcome advice.

Comment: No suggestions to use `geom_jitter` please..

Comment: Related to a previous post of yours (I think) on memory use of factors verses characters is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862856/are-factors-stored-more-efficiently-in-data-table-than-characters/34865113#34865113) by Matt Dowle.